# Rewriting URL to Query String

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

I know how to rewrite in the reverse direction and process the Query String, but I need to create one query string parameter based on the tag or category, in lowercase. Therefore, I can user the query string as search parameter in my page:

e.g.

```
news/tag/Shipping/ ==> http://www.example.com/news/?tag=shipping
news/category/Other/ ==> http://www.example.com/news/?category=other
```

Tried

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^news/([^/]*)$ /?tag=$1 [L]
```

Thank you.

Comment: Can you share what you have tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need 2 rewrite rules.

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^news/([\w-]+)/?$ news/?tag=$1 [L,QSA,NC]

RewriteRule ^news/([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/?$ news/?$1=$2 [L,QSA,NC]
```

Comment: Anyway that Tag or Category could just be assumed to be in the same position in the URL and the final part of the URL is the variable part. I only added Tag to my code to try and make it work correctly. @anubhava.

Comment: In the 2nd rule you can notice that both 2nd and 3rd parts are variables. That should work for all the cases. If you have a different requirement then edit the question with examples.